# why delete in SQL query in PYTHON doesn't commit changes in database?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, delete-row

`DELETE FROM ...` doesn't work. The right parameters are passed to the function. No errors are returned.

I've tried to modify routing, passing parameters by POST and GET, and I've cried a lot in a fetal position.

```
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM food_on_the_table WHERE table_id = %s", table_id) 
food_on_the_table = cursor.fetchall()
records = cursor.fetchall() 
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM food_on_the_table WHERE row_id = %s", row_id)   
conn.commit()
result = cursor.rowcount
message = "rows affected " + str(result)    
cursor.close()
```

No row is deleted from the database. `row_i` is right, `rows affected = 1` as expected.

Comment: `DELETE` works. It's not a function either, nor is it affected by which client program sends the SQL query, much less the language used to create it. The server only sees the SQL query and its parameters if any. If DELETE, one of the most fundamental commands, didn't work in MySQL people would have noticed 25 years ago.

Comment: Most likely, the `row_id` is wrong. Perhaps the `row_id` field is numeric but the parameter is a string that can't be converted to a number or vice versa. `   3` isn't equal to the number 3. Either the field or parameter may contain whitespace. Did you try the same query with another client, eg MySQL Workbench?

Comment: You could use the [general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) or a tracing/profiling tool to check what's actually sent to the server and execute it in MySQL Workbench

Comment: i have of course tried to execute command in the database in phpMyadmin and it did work. row_id is an int in the table, i've tried int(row_id) but it didn't work.
then my question is how is the code 'try: blah blah blah' different than the one i've wrote? why it works while the original one doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
try:
    conn = mysql.connect()
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM food_on_the_table WHERE table_id = %s", table_id)
        food_on_the_table = cursor.fetchall()
        records = food_on_the_table 
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM food_on_the_table WHERE row_id = %s", row_id)

    conn.commit()

finally:
    conn.close()
```

Comment: it worked! Thanks! can you maybe explain why mine doesn't?